# Custom sub taxonomy order by

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I am using Category Order and Taxonomy Terms Order this plugin in WordPress 4.8. Editing custom taxonomy order and save that. But Does not reflect in front end site but after adding one category or update any one category the changes are reflected on the front end. Can you what was the reason then let me know as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

to customize posts and taxonomy order in front-end i usually use this plug-in:
https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/intuitive-custom-post-order/

anyway, check if inside your Query you have something like

```
'order' => XXX
'orderby' => XXX
```

if yes, remove them.